# Como desativar componente no JFrame

Tags: java, window-builder

Tenho dois JFrames o primeiro tem o nome de "Sistema" e outro "Acessar" quando concluir a autenticação no "Acessar" queria que o componente chamado de "mnUsuario" que está descrito abaixo fosse desativado para que eu possa ter um controle sobre os privilégios de cada usuário no programa.

**JFrame: Sistema**

```
public class Sistema extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JMenu mnUsuario;

public void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Look And Feel
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                Sistema frame = new Sistema();
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Sistema() {

    setTitle("Sistema - IBMO");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnArquivo = new JMenu("Arquivo");
    menuBar.add(mnArquivo);

    mnUsuario = new JMenu("Usuário");
    mnArquivo.add(mnUsuario);

    JMenuItem mntmAdicionar_1 = new JMenuItem("Adicionar");
    mntmAdicionar_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            GerenciarUsuario gUsuario = new GerenciarUsuario();
            GerenciarUsuario.main(null);
            gUsuario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
    });
    mnUsuario.add(mntmAdicionar_1);

    JMenuItem mntmModificar_1 = new JMenuItem("Modificar");
    mnUsuario.add(mntmModificar_1);

    JMenuItem mntmPesquisar_1 = new JMenuItem("Pesquisar");
    mnUsuario.add(mntmPesquisar_1);

    JMenu mnMembro = new JMenu("Membro");
    mnArquivo.add(mnMembro);

    JMenuItem mntmAdicionar = new JMenuItem("Adicionar");
    mnMembro.add(mntmAdicionar);

    JMenuItem mntmModificar = new JMenuItem("Modificar");
    mnMembro.add(mntmModificar);

    JMenuItem mntmPesquisar = new JMenuItem("Pesquisar");
    mnMembro.add(mntmPesquisar);

    JMenuItem mntmSair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
    mntmSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            int opcao = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você realmente deseja sair do Sistema?", "Informação", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

            // Validar Confirmação
            if(opcao == 0) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                // Continuar
            }

        }
    });
    mnArquivo.add(mntmSair);

// Menu Ajuda
    JMenu mnAjuda = new JMenu("Ajuda");
    menuBar.add(mnAjuda);

    // Ajuda -> Sobre
    JMenuItem mntmSobre = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
    mnAjuda.add(mntmSobre);

// JPanel
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}
public JMenu mnUsuario() {
    return mnUsuario;
}
}
```

**JFrame: Acessar**

```
if(grupo.equals("suporte")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você pertece ao Grupo: " + grupo, "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            new Sistema().main(null);
                            dispose();
                        } else if(grupo.equals("lider")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você pertece ao Grupo: " + grupo, "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            new Sistema().main(null);
                            dispose();
                        } else if(grupo.equals("auxiliar")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você pertece ao Grupo: " + grupo, "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            new Sistema().main(null);
                            dispose();
                        } else if(grupo.equals("supervisor")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você pertece ao Grupo: " + grupo, "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            new Sistema().main(null);
                            dispose();
```

**JFrame: Sistema**

```
    public class Sistema extends JFrame {

// Variáveis
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

// JFrame
    public void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                // Look And Feel
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            // Frame
                try {
                    Sistema frame = new Sistema();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

// Iniciar
    public Sistema() {

    // Sistema
        setTitle("Sistema - IBMO");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 600);

    // Menubar
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        // Arquivo
        JMenu mnArquivo = new JMenu("Arquivo");
        menuBar.add(mnArquivo);

        JMenu mnUsuario = new JMenu("Usuário");
        mnArquivo.add(mnUsuario);

        JMenuItem mntmAdicionar_1 = new JMenuItem("Adicionar");
        mntmAdicionar_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                GerenciarUsuario gUsuario = new GerenciarUsuario();
                GerenciarUsuario.main(null);
                gUsuario.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        });
        mnUsuario.add(mntmAdicionar_1);

        JMenuItem mntmModificar_1 = new JMenuItem("Modificar");
        mnUsuario.add(mntmModificar_1);

        JMenuItem mntmPesquisar_1 = new JMenuItem("Pesquisar");
        mnUsuario.add(mntmPesquisar_1);

        // Arquivo -> Membro
        JMenu mnMembro = new JMenu("Membro");
        mnArquivo.add(mnMembro);

        // Arquivo -> Membro (Adicionar)
        JMenuItem mntmAdicionar = new JMenuItem("Adicionar");
        mnMembro.add(mntmAdicionar);

        // Arquivo -> Membro (Modificar)
        JMenuItem mntmModificar = new JMenuItem("Modificar");
        mnMembro.add(mntmModificar);

        // Arquivo -> Membro (Pesquisar)
        JMenuItem mntmPesquisar = new JMenuItem("Pesquisar");
        mnMembro.add(mntmPesquisar);

        // Arquivo -> Sair
        JMenuItem mntmSair = new JMenuItem("Sair");
        mntmSair.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                // Confirmação para Sair
                int opcao = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Você realmente deseja sair do Sistema?", "Informação", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);

                // Validar Confirmação
                if(opcao == 0) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    // Continuar
                }

            }
        });
        mnArquivo.add(mntmSair);

    // Menu Ajuda
        JMenu mnAjuda = new JMenu("Ajuda");
        menuBar.add(mnAjuda);

        // Ajuda -> Sobre
        JMenuItem mntmSobre = new JMenuItem("Sobre");
        mnAjuda.add(mntmSobre);

    // JPanel
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: `mnUsuario.setEnable(false); ` já tentou?

Comment: Sim, já. mnUsuario.setVisible(false) também.

Comment: Usando [JDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) essa tarefa talvez fique mais facil, pois assim, você pode fazer com que o jdialog retorne uma booleana informando se o usuario está autenticado.

Comment: Como posso fazer pelo JDialog?

Comment: Qual é o Jframe que é chamado primeiro: sistema ou acessar?

Comment: Primeiro é Acessar e o Acessar chama o Sistema.

Comment: Pode adicionar o seu código do JFrame acessar? Se ela é a principal, faz mais sentido o main e todo aquele tratamento de erros para o L&F estarem no Acessar.

Comment: Foi adicionado.

Comment: No caso, era o JFrame `Acessar` .

Comment: Me desculpe a ignorância. Como assim campeão?

Comment: Junior, na pergunta você diz que tem **dois jframes, um com nome Sistema e outro de nome Acessar**. O `Sistema` você já havia postado, o `Acessar` você só postou a validação.